# Cannot install debug APK

Tags: android, gradle

I'm generating with Gradle my APK by using:

```
gradle assembleRelease
```

and

```
gradle assembleDebug
```

I have the same configuration for them (except for signing):

```
        buildTypes {
            debug {
                // En Scala obligatorio pasar por Proguard.
                runProguard true
                proguardFiles file('proguard.txt')
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
            release {
                runProguard true
                proguardFiles file('proguard.txt')
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
```

The question is why the debug APK is 3.3 Mb, whereas the release on is only 2.4 Mb.
This fact prevents me to installed the debug APK to the device:

```
E/installd(  151): dexopt failed on '/data/dalvik-cache/data@app@my.package-1.apk@classes.dex' res = 11
E/PackageManager(  277): Package my.package has mismatched uid: 10061 on disk, 10062 in settings
E/dalvikvm( 2090): LinearAlloc exceeded capacity (5242880), last=41944
E/dalvikvm( 2090): VM aborting
E/installd(  151): dexopt failed on '/data/dalvik-cache/data@app@my.package-1.apk@classes.d
```

The release APK installs without problems.

I was using SBT instead of Gradle, and I could also install the debug APK.

I'm using a real low budget device: Samsung Galaxy Mini with Android version 2.3.
Probably with more powerful devices, there would be no problem.

Comment: Why do you think the size is the problem? I would turn proguard of and see if that fixes it. I don't see a reason to use our for debug anyway.

Comment: I need ProGuard, because I'm using a small portion of the big Scala runtime library.  Certainly, I could use only the release one.

Comment: Confirmed that with a 4.4.2 device it works ok.

Comment: My guess is it's related to: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22586

Comment: Since I'm using SBT instead of Gradle, I'm not suffering this problem any more.  :-)